# Which hand wins

Tags: poker-texas-holdem

The community has King, King, Queen, Queen, 2.
Bob has 10, 7 in the hole.
Charlie has 3, 3 in the hole.

Does Bob win because he has high card, or does Charlie win because he pocket 3 pair?

Comment: Hint: what are the best five-card hands each player can make?

Comment: So the pair of 3s doesn't matter?

Comment: I thought that the original wording was confusing, so I made it simple. If you liked your wording better, you can roll back my edit (I won't mess it up again).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

No, the pair of 3s doesn't matter.  You can't make 3 pairs with 5 cards.
Bob makes K,K,Q,Q,10.
Charlie makes K,K,Q,Q,3.
Bob takes the hand.